PowerShell 7 + SqlServer module connection error
I have a very basic PowerShell script that works in PS 5, but not PS 7.
Here's the code:
$cr = Import-Clixml -Path 'C:\Users\{me}\Desktop\cred.xml'
$cs = ('Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3};Persist Security Info=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;' -f $env:ComputerName, 'master', $cr.UserName, $cr.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
$rs = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query 'select name DatabaseName from sys.databases order by name' -ConnectionString $cs
$rs

It executes every time when I run this using a PowerShell 5 command prompt: (i.e. .\demo.ps1)
It fails every time when I run this using a PowerShell 7 command prompt with this error:

Invoke-Sqlcmd: C:\Users{me}\Desktop\demo.ps1:4
Line |
4 |  $rs = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query 'select name DatabaseName from sys.databas …
|        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server
was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured
to allow remote connections. (provider: HTTP Provider, error: 0 - )
None of those issues are an issue for PS5 - why are they an issue with 7?

I've tried moving all the connection string attributes to the Invoke-Sqlcmd command. I feel like I've tried every combination of connection:

trusted (I'm in sysadmin role)
SqlConnection (that's the norm for us)
move TrustServerCertificate from $CS to PS cmd
include TrustServerCertificate in both $CS & PS cmd
verified multiple times that remote connections are enabled (even though it's a local call)
the instance name is the default (machine name)
checked my local firewall rules


It's odd that it's mentioning HTTP Provider. Probably you have newer Microsoft.Data.SqlClient-based versions of the SqlServer module installed in PowerShell 7's user profile that don't exist in your PowerShell 5 user profile. Compare the outputs of Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Sql*"} | Format-Table Name,Version,Path between the two.

I think it is a the datasource.  You are not referencing a valid instance of the SQL Server.  I do not think it is an issue with PS.  Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to server and see if it works.  Make sure you PS is using the same instance of the server that is in the login window of SSMS.

@jdweng it's my laptop. For the Data Source I've tried; ".", "local", "(local)" and $env:ComputerName. All of those worked with  PS 5, but not PS 7.  It's a default local installation of SQL Server, there's no network call involved.

@AlwaysLearning - I'll give this a try tomorrow.  Thar said, I'm pretty sure there's only the one SqlServer module.  I'll include version number with any update.

Can you connect with SQL Server Management Studio?   The instance is on the login window.

@jdweng - yes.  The issue is completely with PS 7.  My primary job is as a SQL Developer/DBA - so I know how to connect to SQL Server via multiple methods.

@AlwaysLearning - well I'll be!
    Name      Version    Path
    ----      -------    ----
    SqlServer 22.3.0     C:\Users\phunter008\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\22.3.0\SqlServer.psd1
    SqlServer 21.1.18256 C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18256\SqlServer.psd1
    SQLPS     1.0        C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\SQLPS.psd1
    SQLPS     16.0       C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\SQLPS.psd1


@AlwaysLearning
Using both a PS 5 & 7 command prompts:

Import-Module SqlServer
Get-Module SqlServer
return different results:
In PS 5 = SqlServer 22.3.0
In PS 7 = SqlServer 22.1.1
I was definitely not expecting this!


I uninstalled all SqlServer modules and reinstalled the latest version 22.3.0.
I then ran the code demo again.  Still works in PS 5, but not PS 7.  I think I'll try going from the other side and check what versions of PS the SqlServer module supports.

did you check the log files with SQL Server Management Studio?  The log file is in the explorer under management.  The log files should show a login for every PS query with the Group and User Name.  Is the database using Windows Credentials or SQL Credentials?  Most systems will not allow with windows credentials a username and password.  Best to use Integrated Security = true.  If you do not see the login with SSMS than you are not using the correct instance.  Use same instance as the SSMS login window.  What connection string are you using with other methods?

It appears that no matter what I do - the SqlServer module will not work in PowerShell 7.
I reworked my script to call a function that leverages System.Data.  It's not as flexible as the Invoke-SqlCmd function in the SQL Server Module - but it works for my needs.
Thanks to @AlwaysLearning

The SqlServer module works fine in PS7, I use it just about every day. What you've not told us is the version of SQL Server you're connecting to. I'd suspect you've got a pre-SQL Server 2016 instance that hasn't had all of the required service packs and cumulative updates installed to support TLS 1.2 connectivity (as is needed for SQL Server 2008-2014).

@AlwaysLearning SQL 2022 Developer Edition.  Recently applied latest CU (14 I think it was)
